# Positioning Nav Bar with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble positioning my vertical navigation bar to the left of my content Div. Here is what I have and what I want:

[image]

The problem, is that it's a fixed position so it's different for monitors that are not a similar size. So I'm guessing I'll need to have relative positioning but I'm not too sure on how to do it.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Home Page </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "styles/styling.css" />
</head>

<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav">.....(Just nav bar stuff)


<div class="content">
<h1>abcd</h1>

<p>abcd</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content { 
background-color: #FFFFFF; 
width: 650px; 
padding: 20px;
margin: auto; 
word-wrap: break-word 
}

.container {
position: fixed;
top: 151px;
left: 420px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you please provide an jsfiddle or live example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed position will help you keep your menu visible when you scroll down. Otherwise, you should not use it.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="one-third column">
      <ul class="yourmenu">xxx</ul> 
      <div class="filler"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="two-thirds column">
      Your page content here
  </div>
</div>

<style>
    .container {width:960px;margin:auto;}
    .column {float:left;position:relative;}
    .one-third {width:320px;}
    .two-thirds {width:640px;}
    .filler {width:100%;height:10px;}
    .yourmenu {position:fixed;top:100px;} /* do not define left, because it will fix the screen and not the column div */
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I had to change the values of the container and the "yourmenu" top alignment to get it to fit with mine but all is working. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Use percent (%) instead of pixels (px).

Comment: Can you be more specific? What value should be changed?

Comment: Yes. Change "px" for "%". Does this help you understand?

Comment: What rule? Width? Height?

Comment: It depends on how you want the page to scale. Typically you want the width to be scalable (so percent), with widgets (such as navbars) a set height (px).

Comment: So you should describe this in your answer.

Comment: No I shouldn't. The OP didn't ask how his page should be designed. Dookie's answer would have given logic to the changes of PX to %, I simply gave a  hint. You're not being helpful.

Comment: See [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): *Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better*.